# Unable to pass data from view to controller ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.net MVC5 application, and there is one form for allowing the user to input his phone number. I am getting null value in the controller when I submit the form.

the view:

```
@model PhoneNumberDto

@using (Html.BeginForm("PreTransfer", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="input-group text-dark border-dark">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">+</span> 
                    </div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PhoneNumber,
                                    new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", @type = "number", @inputmode = "tel", @style = "color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248)", @placeholder = "Country code and phone number "}})
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" value="Save" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new {@style = "color: red"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new PhoneNumberDto();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PreTransfer(PhoneNumberDto phoneNumber)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var viewModel = phoneNumber;
        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class PhoneNumberDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{10,12})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a correct number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing phoneNumber to phoneNumberDto in PreTransfer method in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature should have phoneNumber as a string

```
public ActionResult PreTransfer(string phoneNumber)
```

alternatively there is `Request.Form("PhoneNumber")` that should work too.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to a name conflict. ASP.NET knows about `PhoneNumber` string property on your form and can map it to `string phoneNumber` parameter in the method public `ActionResult PreTransfer(string phoneNumber)`.

Also, ASP.NET knows about `PhoneNumberDto` but just can't map in the property with an existing name. So, you can change the name of the method parameter to any other and your code starts work correctly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PreTransfer(PhoneNumberDto model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

[Here is an article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1078491/Creating-Forms-in-ASP-NET-MVC) about two ways to pass parameters from controller. For example, if you have a DTO with three parameters both this signatures are correct:

```
[HttpPost]
public void FormOne(string textBoxStringData, int textBoxIntData, string checkboxData)
{
    //Do something
}

[HttpPost]
public void FormTwo(YourDto model)
{
    //Do something with formData
}
```